# Is there a status page for Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, downtime

Stack Overflow was down a few minutes ago, and I noticed that there is no way to see whether it's a local problem or the server is down. It would be nice to have a status page like Github has (https://status.github.com/).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

https://www.stackstatus.net is the offsite status page/blog. Then [@stackstatus on twitter](https://twitter.com/StackStatus).

Comment: https://www.stackstatus.net/ is not real time, it's updated only after a really major downtime with the reason. The twitter is more live and updated.

Comment: I actually used https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+status => no useful result

Comment: @TomášFejfar Technically, Stack Overflow is always two words. If you Google for "stack overflow status" the stackstatus.net site is #5 (granted that's still quite low). But "stack exchange status" or "stackexchange status" does get stackstatus.net and the twitter account #1 or #2.

Comment: Well there is some SEO/branding issue then! Because "Where did you find this?" "On stackoverflow" and not "On stack overflow" :) At least for me and my social circle...

Answer (score 4):

There is this: http://www.isup.me/https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: That's what I used actually ;) But I thought that there should be something more

Answer (score 2):

For real time updates and some hidden gems about their job, you can also follow the developers directly.

[Marc](https://twitter.com/marcgravell) and [Nick](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver) should be enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

[We have a status blog.](https://www.stackstatus.net/) And stackstatus@twitter.