# iOS app should direct users to helpful status when the site is totally down

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, help

There is already a [request to have read-only mode shown to users of the iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231167/provide-an-indicator-that-site-is-in-read-only-mode) when the site is read-only. I'd like to also request that the app actually direct users to the [canonical / official status resources](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203585/is-there-a-status-page-for-stack-exchange-sites) that are maintained when [network errors arise](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/481178798759890944):

- https://www.stackstatus.net
- https://twitter.com/StackStatus

Ideally, these links would also be in the help section as links or if the app can actually consume the data posted, but the app currently (v1.0.1.85) draws a blank blue screen when starting up if the API is down and/or DNS is not resolving due to network errors. It also has a black failed message if the app was working and cached some data locally before the site outage starts.

Neither of these current iOS app indications allow users of the app to find the cause of errors or start troubleshooting if the app is broken, their network is broken or the end point services are broken.

Comment: @shadow_wizard This doesn't cover Read-Only mode (except to acknowledge a similar request for that notification) so I rolled back your tag edits. I would ask that something be placed in help (per the tag - "how help and information is provided to users") at the least and more interactive coding if possible.

Comment: Fair enough, cheers!